# Make [nimrod] a synonym of [nim-lang]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Nim was recently renamed from Nimrod, so it's a good idea for the tags [nimrod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nimrod) to be synomized with [nim-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim-lang).

Comment: You should provide sources or at least some more explanation as to way.  But according to [this blog](http://nim-lang.org/news.html#Z2014-12-09-new-website-design), the new version seems to break compatibility slightly.  As such, it might be better to just leave them as separate tags so users working with the older partially-compatible version can identify posts about the older version

Comment: @psubsee2003 I disagree. It's still the same language, and version names can be used to handle your compatibility concerns (see [tag:python]  and [tag:python-3.x]).

Answer (score 2):

I agree and think that [nimrod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nimrod) should be a synonym of (and later merged into) [nim-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim-lang) as they basically mean the same thing. That would seem better than simply removing the tag and retagging the questions, as it will preserve the connection between the names in the tag page.

This is the wiki for the [nimrod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nimrod) tag which currently has 31 questions:

> [nimrod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nimrod) is **the deprecated name for Nim**, a statically typed, imperative programming language [...]

<sup>emphasis and tag link mine</sup>

On the other hand, [nim-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim-lang) has 508 questions and states:

> Nim (formerly known as "Nimrod") is a statically typed, imperative programming language [...]

Interestingly, 28 out of the 31 questions tagged `nimrod` ***are also tagged `nim-lang`*** (so removing the tag doesn't change much).

From the 3 questions solely tagged `nimrod`, [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70524267/nim-how-to-access-raw-post-request-body-in-prologue-framework) [of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486599/cast-ptr-ptr-to-nim-array) mention Nim in the title and/or body, and there is only [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47301187/nimrod-hunter-installation-issue-gives-message-nothing-to-commit-working-dir) which is a bit old and seems to actually be about Nimrod. Assuming no new questions will be made with Nimrod (as that's no longer the name of the language), I think it is pointless to keep it for one question (with no answers) and this question can just get `nim-lang` instead.

---

<sup>This answer was adapted from [a duplicate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416020/merge-the-two-nimrod-tags) I made, before becoming aware of this question.</sup>