# Can the [nim] tag be renamed to [nim-lang]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

Questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50788976/revisions) keep showing that people presume the tag [nim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim) actually stands for [nim-game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim-game). Since the nim tag comes from the [nimrod programming language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281660/make-nimrod-a-synonym-of-nim), maybe it could be renamed to [nim-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim-lang) to require new questions to choose explicitly if the question is about the nim game or the nim language.

The programming language website also uses the `-lang` suffix https://nim-lang.org to help with google searches.

Comment: There are 242 [tag:nim] questions. If anyone would volunteer to manually check whether they should be `lang` or `game` and re-tag before the rename, sure.

Comment: @Mast - I think it would be easier if [nim-lang] were to already exist, so that we know we're done when there are no more plain [nim] questions. For me the next best alternative would be to use [nimrod] until there are no more [nim] questions, and then rename/synonymize [nimrod] with [nim-lang].

Comment: @Mast challenge accepted

Comment: @anearwig, did you complete the challenge which you accepted? If yes, then I can rename it now.

Comment: I can go ahead and rename the tag as soon as anyone makes sure that all the posts in [tag:nim] are related to the language and not the game.

Comment: @BhargavRao I did just review all of them, all are related to the nim programming language.

Comment: Cool, thanks so much for your efforts. I renamed the tag. The next step is to review if [nimrod] needs to be a synonym of [nim-lang]. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281660/make-nimrod-a-synonym-of-nim-lang.