# Merge [nim] into [nim-lang]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Back in 2019 [nim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim) was [renamed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369305/735926#comment720398_369305) as [nim-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim-lang) but three months ago the tag was [re-created](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74236941/revisions) and it has [a few questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim?tab=Newest) now (22 vs. 585 for [nim-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim-lang)). Both tags are used for the exact same language, as one can see from the questions and from the tag wiki.

Would it be possible to merge the new tag into the old one?

Comment: Would probably make sense to make then synonyms.

Comment: No clue why a synonym wasn't added in the first place

Comment: ... except the synonym UI says there has been a synonym since 2015? Either that or it wasn't approved until just now, but I have no way to check

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine seeing that there have been no renames until now, seems that's the case; the date is when the synonym was proposed, like on [pending approval](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested). But I guess the tag is ambiguous since it may refer to the [tag:nim-game] instead, not the programming language. The alternative is to block [tag:nim] tag instead.

Comment: Never mind, disregard about blocking it. Questions about [tag:nim-game] are very rare compared to [tag:nim-lang] that wrong usage may not be a problem.