# Merge the two Nim(rod) tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

<sup>Disclaimer: I am no expert of that language, simply encountered this tag duplication and bringing it up.</sup>

---

> [nimrod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nimrod) is **the deprecated name for Nim**, a statically typed, imperative programming language [...]

<sup>emphasis and tag link mine</sup>

This is the wiki for the `nimrod` tag which currently has 31 questions.

On the other hand, [nim-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim-lang) has 508 questions and states:

> Nim (formerly known as "Nimrod") is a statically typed, imperative programming language [...]

Interestingly, 28 out of the 31 questions tagged `nimrod` ***are also tagged `nim-lang`*** (so removing the tag doesn't change much).

From the 3 questions solely tagged `nimrod`, [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70524267/nim-how-to-access-raw-post-request-body-in-prologue-framework) [of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486599/cast-ptr-ptr-to-nim-array) mention Nim in the title and/or body, and there is only [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47301187/nimrod-hunter-installation-issue-gives-message-nothing-to-commit-working-dir) which is a bit old and seems to actually be about Nimrod. Assuming no new questions will be made with Nimrod (as that's no longer the name), I think it is pointless to keep it for one question (with no answers) and this question can just get `nim-lang` instead.

My suggestion is to make `nimrod` a synonym of (and merge it into) `nim-lang` as they basically mean the same thing. That would seem better than simply removing the tag and retagging the questions, as it will preserve the connection between the names in the tag page.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369305/can-the-nim-tag-be-renamed-to-nim-lang#comment720398_369305